# WordPress - не применяются стили

Tags: css

**Создал функцию в functions.php:**

```
function srdnl_service_list_item_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(
        shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'title' => '',
                'image' => '',
                'col' => 12,
                'toggled' => 'md'
            ),
            $atts
        )
    );

    $return  = '<div class="service-list-item text-center">';
    $return .= '    <img class="imgServiceList" src="'.$atts['image'].'" alt="'.$atts['title'].'" title="'.$atts['title'].'">';
    $return .= '    <span class="title hidden">'.$atts['title'].'</span>';
    $return .= '    <span class="content hidden">'.$content.'</span>';
    $return .= '</div>';
    return do_shortcode($return);
}
```

На сайте всё нормально отображается, но почему-то не работают стили... К примеру, прописываю:

```
service-list-item text-center content {
    color:red;
}
```

и на сайте ничего не меняется. Прописываю:

```
imgServiceList {
    height:400px;
    width:200px;
}
```

тоже никаких изменений. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так указываю?[image: код]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде пропущены точки перед селекторами

```
.imgServiceList{
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
}

.service-list-item .content{
   color:red;
}
```

Это будет работать

Comment: Благодарю. Забыл про них совсем...